# Need help identifying year of Ultegra rear derailleur

Tags: shimano, derailleur

I am helping a friend sell triathlon bike (he recently bought a mountain bike and does not need to have more bikes sitting around), and so I am trying to gather more information around the bike to provide as many details as possible to potential buyers. It's a 2009 orbea Aletta. He's got a FSA front derailleur and Shimano 105 shifters (he converted the tri bike into a roadie). According to the BBB, it does not look like the bike is worth a whole lot, but it is better than nothing! 
If anyone has any clue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Not sure why it matters.  If the thing is unbent and with no wear it could be 30 years old and still in fine condition.

Comment: If you look at the back of the body, the side facing away from the camera in this photo, there's a fair chance there will be a model number on it.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRHicks - You are correct. It doe not really matter. This is more for personal knowledge and also in case a potential buyer asks, but I agree with you, the derailleur is in great condition overall.

Comment: @armb thank you! This is a very useful tip. I'll take a look. It seems like it is a 6600 and according to Ryder_X, it is a very reliable derailleur.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is an Ultegra 6600, made from 2005 to 2008 (according to Wikipedia). Not sure you will be able to narrow it down to the exact year.

Comment: It is 6600 rear derailleur. Best shifting cable actuated Ultegra rear derailleur I have ever owned. Better than even the modern fair (e.g., 6800).